# adjusting the position of a linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the result of my layout

[image: capture]

My problem is that I don't want the distance between "new asset" ( witch shows when clicking on the button new asset) and "old asset" to be too long , "old asset" has to be just below the button and "new asset" should be placed just on top of old asset when clicking on the button  .

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Build a list of significant assets for the organization"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/addasset"
            style="@style/btnStyleBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text=" + add new asset" />

         <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/newa"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.01"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

             </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/old"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.01"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp" >

             </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my java code :

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assets, container, false);

            final LinearLayout newa = (LinearLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.newa);
            final LinearLayout old = (LinearLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.old);

            Button add_asset = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addasset);
            add_asset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {



                    TextView tv1 = new TextView(v.getContext());
                    tv1.setText("New asset ");
                    tv1.setTextSize(14);
                    tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                    tv1.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 10);
                    newa.addView(tv1);
                }
            });

            TextView tv = new TextView(rootView.getContext());
            tv.setText("old asset ");
            tv.setTextSize(14);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv.setPadding(0, 15, 0, 10);
            old.addView(tv);

            return rootView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you are misunderstanding `weights`. The parent `layout` should have a `weightSum` then give child `Views` `weights` to equal that some to distribute the amount of space they take up according to what you need.

Second, you have `android:padding="10dp"` in each `LinearLayout` so there will effectively be 20dp `padding` between each. Remove those if you don't want that space.

You have `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in what appears to be an empty `LinearLayout`. This looks like it could be removed.

I think the `weight` is probably what is giving you the most trouble. Remove that

However, I think I would use a `RelativeLayout`, you could have the two `LinearLayouts` still if you want, and specify `android:layout_below="@+id/contain"` to put the second `LinearLayout` below the first

Also note that `fill_parent` is deprecated and you should use `match_parent` instead

Answer (score 0):

Change xml code of linear layouts to this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newa"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/old"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

</LinearLayout>
```